# Recursive Typing in Python 3.5+

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, type-hinting, python-typing

In Python 3.5, type annotations were added (see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html)).

Is there a way of defining recursive type annotations, such as for a tree-like structure?

```
class Employee(object):
    def __init__(self, name: str, reports: List[Employee]):
       self.name = name
       self.reports = reports
```

In the above, it doesn't seem as though the annotation `List[Employee]` works. Running the code results in this error:

`NameError: name 'Employee' is not defined`

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can use [Forward References](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#forward-references) as defined in PEP 484

> A situation where this occurs commonly is the definition of a
>   container class, where the class being defined occurs in the signature
>   of some of the methods. For example, the following code (the start of
>   a simple binary tree implementation) does not work:
>
> ```
> class Tree:
>     def __init__(self, left: Tree, right: Tree):
>         self.left = left
>         self.right = right
> ```
>
> To address this, we write:
>
> ```
> class Tree:
>     def __init__(self, left: 'Tree', right: 'Tree'):
>         self.left = left
>         self.right = right
> ```
>
> It is allowable to use string literals as part of a type hint, for
>   example:
>
> ```
> class Tree:
>     ...
>     def leaves(self) -> List['Tree']:
> ```

Comment: Note that this will not be necessary since Python3.10, and can be optionally avoided with `from __future__ import annotations`, see the table at the bottom of https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/__future__.html

Comment: Note that Python 3.10's annotations change ended up causing problems but it was too late to take it back in 3.10, so there is discussion of changing it yet again. See for example [PEP-649](https://peps.python.org/pep-0649/).