# Python typing doesn't accept | union with stringized annotation

Tags: python, recursion, python-typing, typing, ordinal

This works:

```py
from typing import Union, Callable

class Ordinal:
  def __init__(self, children : Union[None, 'Ordinal']):
    self.children = children
```

This doesn't:

```py
from typing import Union, Callable

class Ordinal:
  def __init__(self, children : None | 'Ordinal'):
    self.children = children

# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'NoneType' and 'str'
```

I'm fine using the first one, but would like to know what's going on here, so I make sure the first one isn't actually just implementing something entirely different.

(for clarity, I'm defining the type `Ordinal` recursively with [stringized annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38340808/recursive-typing-in-python-3-5).)

Comment: Check your Python version.  Using `|` to union types is relatively new.

Comment: @Samwise The version's 3.10.11, and it works fine if I replace the `'Ordinal'` with any type other than a stringized annotation -- even `Callable[[int], 'Ordinal']`.

Comment: Are you looking for `from __future__ import annotations`‽

Comment: @deceze Wait that actually worked, thanks, but I don't understand the magic trick.

Comment: `|` isn't overloaded to handle `str` arguments; the `__future__` import disables runtime evaluation of type hints, so the definition of `|` doesn't matter.

Comment: @chepner Wait, it disables evaluation of type hints? Isn't that bad?

Comment: It "disables" the evaluation of the annotation expression and just takes it as a string as is. That string can later be evaluated by type checking tools as needed. You could always do this by writing strings as annotations, the future import just makes it implicitly so always, which is/should/will be the default behaviour eventually. See the duplicate linked above.

Comment: Evaluation of type hints is what Python will do at runtime. It's separate from a static analyzer like `mypy`, which does not execute any code, from using them to perform type checking.

Comment: To be clear, `mypy` itself is fine with `None | 'Ordinal'`; it's Python that can't evaluate it. (Function annotations are arbitrary expression, though expressions not consistent with the semantics defined by PEP 484 are deprecated.)